# Onchange event in system.xml magento

Tags: magento

Can anyone tell me how i can do that.I created custom module with system.xml.In system.xml I create two elements, one select option and other text-box.I want to display text-box on specific value of select option. My code is :
Select option

```
<email_sender translate="label">
  <label>E-mail Sender</label>
  <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_identity</source_model>
  <sort_order>0</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</email_sender>
```

Textbox that want to be displayed on select option is :

```
<interval translate="label">
  <label>Interval</label>
  <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
  <sort_order>4</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

.
While for select i use this chunk of code in model

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        array('value'=>'show_txtbx', 'label'=>Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Show Textbox')),
        array('value'=>'hide', 'label'=>Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Hide')),

    );
}
```

How can i do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I got my answer after some extra search.Thanks to Alan for such nice tutorials .Here is the link where I got my answer.[Click Here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I tried above-given link but in my case, it didn't work with that syntax. 
The core concept of adding dependency is correct, but the syntax is somewhat different I guess. You need to add

```
<depends>
    <field id="custom">1</field>
</depends>
```

Here is a link which worked for me :
https://webkul.com/blog/create-dependant-field-admin-configuration-magento-2/